# Filter timestamp rows in one table based on start time & End time given in another table

Tags: r, dplyr

I have one table that contains downtime data which looks like this

```
| Machine No | Start Time       | End Time         |
|------------|------------------|------------------|
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:05 | 01-01-2021 12:15 |
| H19        | 02-01-2021 11:15 | 02-01-2021 13:15 |
| H20        | 01-01-2021 11:15 | 01-01-2021 13:15 |
| H21        | 02-01-2021 09:15 | 02-01-2021 13:55 |
| H22        | 02-01-2021 10:25 | 02-01-2021 10:35 |
```

And I have a value stream data which looks like this, which is basically appended for all machines together

```
| Machine No | timestamp        | Value |
|------------|------------------|-------|
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:00 | 34    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:01 | 74    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:02 | 43    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:03 | 60    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:04 | 68    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:05 | 17    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:06 | 38    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:07 | 91    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:08 | 65    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:09 | 80    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:10 | 67    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:11 | 78    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:12 | 43    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:13 | 53    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:14 | 92    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:15 | 11    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:16 | 75    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:17 | 61    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:18 | 82    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:19 | 50    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:20 | 65    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:21 | 23    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:22 | 80    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:23 | 55    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:24 | 61    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:25 | 11    |
| H18        | 01-01-2021 12:26 | 98    |
```

I want to remove the rows containing data from the value stream table that is in between the start time and end time mentioned in the downtime data table. How do I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 1):

You can join `df1` and `df2` by `Machine.No`, convert the columns to `POSIXct` format and keep only rows which are outside of `Start.Time` and `End.Time`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = 'Machine.No') %>%
  mutate(across(c(Start.Time,  End.Time,timestamp), lubridate::dmy_hm)) %>%
  filter(!(timestamp >= Start.Time & timestamp <= End.Time))
```

Or in base R :

```
res <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'Machine.No')
res[2:4] <- lapply(res[2:4], as.POSIXct, format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', tz = 'UTC')
subset(res, !(timestamp >= Start.Time & timestamp <= End.Time))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, i dont think this is working as what it is doing is that 1 lacs rows in Valuestream and 10k rows in downtime, when merged by inner join is getting replicated to around 29lacs. Our Aim is to simply remove the Value stream data within the timerange mentioned in the Downtime table for each machine respectively

Comment: That can happen if `df1` has duplicate Machine No. In this example you have only 1 row for each Machine No. What is the first value returned when you do `df1 %>% count(Machine.No, sort = TRUE) %>% head`